# Getting Index out of range exception

Tags: c#, list, class

My Main problem is : if i add "N" group to company and check it in the last , i see all of "Man"s arrange into all of groups like together ?

i this my problem is in the definition of class or references .

This is my code :

```
    public class Man
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public int Stoptime { get; set; }
        public Boolean Lunch { get; set; }
        public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }
        public DateTime Departure { get; set; }
        public int LunchTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public List<Man> People { get; set; }
        public double Speed { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
        public double Surcharge { get; set; }
        public double TotalRate { get; set; }
    }
    public class Company
    {
        public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public Group BestGroup { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
        public double Surcharge { get; set; }
        public double FullRate { get; set; }
    }

    private List<Man> ShufflePosts(List<Man> ShufflePeoples)
    {
        List<Man> Temp = ShufflePeoples;
        List<Man> Commixed = new List<Man>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        do
        {
            int shf = rand.Next(0, Temp.Count);
            Commixed.Add(Temp[shf]);
            Temp.RemoveAt(shf);
        } while (Temp.Count > 1);

        Commixed.Add(Temp[0]);
        return Commixed;
    }


    public void CAStart(List<Man> Peoples)
    {

        var _Race = new Company();
        _Race.Groups = new List<Group>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var Gr = new Group();
            Gr.People = ShufflePosts(Peoples);
            _Race.Groups.Add(Gr);
        }
    }
```

In the code `Commixed.Add(Temp[0]);` VS show me error **index out of range**.
I check the variable and see below data:

`ShufflePeoples.Count = 0, Temp.Count = 0, Commixed.Count = 1`

Why this happens ?
Where is my problem ?

Comment: BTW - for next time ask by the error you get - Then you would have found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loop to avoid `index out of range` error:

```
  while (Temp.Count > 0)
    {
        int shf = rand.Next(0, Temp.Count);
        Commixed.Add(Temp[shf]);
        Temp.RemoveAt(shf);
    };
```

When you remove item from `Temp`, you also remove it from `ShufflePeoples` because you refer `Temp = ShufflePeoples`, to avoid it, just make new list then copy items from `ShufflePeoples` to `Temp`.

Answer (score 2):

**Why you get the error:**

Your `do while` loop runs until `Temp.Count > 1` isn't true - which will happen when you removed all items from it with line `Temp.RemoveAt(shf);`.

Then you try accessing Temp[0] (the first item) but temp is empty and you get an `index out of range` error.

Try to change your loop's condition and avoid accessing a specific position in the collection without checking that that position exists. Or better still use a simple while instead and then you won't need to specially address the last item in `Temp`

---

**A nice solution for shuffling:**

```
var suffled = ShufflePeoples.OrderBy(item => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: Why not add items to "Commixed" and Why removed item into ShufflePeoples

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Hope I answer right. you don't get it when you add the items to the `Commixed` because you first chose a position that is for sure in the rand. A nicer way will just be to you a simple `While` loop instead. That way you don't need to address that last item in the collection afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You remove all Temp items in `do-while` loop, so when you try to access `Temp[0]` after loop, it will give you `index out of range`.

Comment: Why not add items to "Commixed" and Why removed item into ShufflePeoples

Answer (score 0):

For the first time, `ShufflePosts` method will remove all the contents of the `ShufflePeoples`.
Therefore the second time you run `ShufflePosts` method, `ShufflePeoples` or `Temp' is basically empty, which means if you try to access`Temp[0]`, it will give you index out of range Exception.

My 2 cents:

1. Avoid assigning `Temp = ShufflePeoples`, instead do Copy Constructor `Temp = new List<Man>(ShufflePeoples)`, to make sure that you do not adjust the parameter accidentally
2. Always check your initial condition of your parameter argument.